# How can I get table via hasMany in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Using Yii2.
I have a tables:

**User**

> (id)

and

**UserContacts**

> (u_id1, u_id2).

In model action:

```
return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'u_id1', 'id' => 'u_id2'])
            ->viaTable('UserContacts', ['id' => 'u_id1', 'id' => 'u_id2']);
```

Prompt how can I get a table with users through viaTable ()?

Comment: does this code give an error? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'u_id2'])
->viaTable(UserContact::tableName(), ['u_id1' => 'id']);
```

Comment: This is the Yii way. Notice the difference between `className()` and `tableName()` in the association spec